# Statically linking a library on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, sqlite

I'm trying to make an XPCOM component for Firefox 3.6.*. It uses libsqlite3 version 3.7.4 compiled statically (with program independent code generation -- -fPIC compiler option). The problem I'm facing is that once Firefox loads the component and it starts executing, the `sqlite3_libversion_number()` returns 3007001 while the macro `SQLITE_LIBVERSION_NUMBER` is defined to 3007004. I'm pretty sure that I'm linking against the correct static sqlite3 library... But how can I double check this? `ldd` output of the generated shared object doesn't list libsqlite3.so as a dependency (although libxul.so, used for creating the XPCOM component, uses libsqlite3.so). How are all sqlite3 function calls resolved to a different version of SQLite?

PS: Is it because the libraries are compiled with -fPIC and Firefox later loads them using `dlopen`?

Answer (score 0):

I be looking at the inclusion order. I have too spent a whole day or something similar wondering why the fseek() failed, not directly on Linux but on Bada, and using Eclipse IDE. The catch was that the same function having the same signature was exported by some "beta" stage .a file from Bada SDK. And I have imported the wrong .a file firstly by accident.

Comment: Yes... Inclusion order very much matters when linking against static libraries, that is resolved using these linker flags (from g++): `-Wl,--start-group <all archive files listed here> -Wl,--end-group`. This will cause the linker to recursively check for symbols in these archives.

Answer (score 0):

In linux, it will perform recursive symbol resolution - i.e if libxul uses libsqlite3 then firefox will indirectly resolve the symbol by including the libsqlite3 from libxul.

This is not the case in AIX machine - where recursive symbol resolution (based on dependent libraries) will not be done.

This might not be the actual problem - but worth checking.

Also check if sqlite3 is backward compatible (which I suppose is), then you can link libxul and other libraries to latest version of sqlite3.

Comment: Yes, SQLite is very much backwards compatible but rebuilding libxul from source is not quite an option right now...

Comment: If libxul is linked to sqlite dynamically then no need to compile libxul. It can be directly put in the LD_LIB_PATH. I am not sure why it must be compiled.